# Как написать уравнение смешивания цветов от точечного источника света?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, цвета

Хочу реализовать простое динамическое освещение в 2D игре. Игра пишется на java 8 с использованием графической библиотеки swing.

Основные требования к шейдеру: источник освещения - перемещающееся точка; свет распространяется в виде круглого градиента без учета препятствий; радиус распространения света от источника может быть любой длины; яркость освещения также может различаться для каждого источника свет; цвет освещения можно задать (в виде rgb). На данный момент реализовано все кроме последнего пункта.

Я выбрал следующий принцип работы шейдера: сперва игровой мир целиком отрисовывается в одну текстуру. При этом изначально все изображения находятся в самом ярком "дневном" освещении. Далее полученное изображение передается шейдеру. Шейдер устанавливает общее освещение связанное с временем суток. Далее шейдер устанавливает освещение для каждого источника света.

Собственно код:

```
//widthWindow и heightWindow - ширина и высота окна
//centerX и centerY - координаты точки источника света
//radius - радиус распространения света
//bright - яркость освещения между текущей и максимальной(середина дня).
//         Задаются в диапозоне [0; 1].
//dataImage - массив пикселей в виде чисел типа int представляющий 
//           изображение текущего кадра после применения освещения для 
//           соответствующего времени суток и часа
//copyDataImage - массив пикселей в виде чисел типа int представляющий 
//           изначальное изображение текущего кадра до применения освещения 
//           для соответствующего времени суток и часа, т.е. изображение
//           имеет максимальный уровень освещения.
//color - цвет освещения
private void setLightForPoint(int widthWindow, int heightWindow,
                              int centerX, int centerY,
                              int radius, double bright,
                              int[] dataImage,
                              int[] copyDataImage,
                              int color) {

    //отрезаем части кргулого градиента освещения, которые выходят за 
    //границы экрана
    int startX = centerX - radius;
    int endX = centerX + radius;
    int startY = centerY - radius;
    int endY = centerY + radius;

    if(startX < 0) startX = 0;
    if(endX > widthWindow - 1) endX = widthWindow - 1;
    if(startY < 0) startY = 0;
    if(endY > heightWindow - 1) endY = heightWindow - 1;

    //устанавливаем освещение для указанной точки-источника света
    for(int x = startX; x <= endX; x++) {
        for(int y = startY; y <= endY; y++) {
            int dx = x - centerX;
            int dy = y - centerY;
            double length = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
            double coffLight = 0;
            if(length < radius) coffLight = (radius - length) / radius;

            int r = copyDataImage[y * widthWindow + x] >> 16 & 0xff;
            int g = copyDataImage[y * widthWindow + x] >> 8 & 0xff;
            int b = copyDataImage[y * widthWindow + x] & 0xff;

            int r2 = dataImage[y * widthWindow + x] >> 16 & 0xff;
            int g2 = dataImage[y * widthWindow + x] >> 8 & 0xff;
            int b2 = dataImage[y * widthWindow + x] & 0xff;

            double dr = (double)r2 / r;
            double dg = (double)g2 / g;
            double db = (double)b2 / b;
            double lightR = dr + (1 - dr) * coffLight * bright;
            double lightG = dg + (1 - dg) * coffLight * bright;
            double lightB = db + (1 - db) * coffLight * bright;
            r = (int) (r * lightR);
            g = (int) (g * lightG);
            b = (int) (b * lightB);

            dataImage[y * widthWindow + x] = dataImage[y * widthWindow + x] & 0xff00ffff | (r << 16);
            dataImage[y * widthWindow + x] = dataImage[y * widthWindow + x] & 0xffff00ff | (g << 8);
            dataImage[y * widthWindow + x] = dataImage[y * widthWindow + x] & 0xffffff00 | b;
        }
    }
}
```

Как видите - параметр color ни как не используется, т.к. я так и не смог понять как реализовать цветное освещение. Как сделать, чтобы свет распространяющийся от источника освещения имел указанный цвет.

Comment: Что-то это не похоже на шейдеры.. Почему у вас `color` имеет тип `int` ?

Comment: Это небось какой-то мазахизм из javax.

Comment: Kromster, для хранения цвета я использую число типа int стандартным способом - старшие байт для хранения alpha значения, следующий за ним для хранения значения красного составляющего пикселя, следующие байты для хранения зелёной и синей составляющей соответственно.

Comment: @Bakuard просто в шейдерах работают типично с цветов в виде 4-компонентного вектора чисел с плавающей точкой от 0 до 1. У вас не шейдер.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос удалось решить с помощью простого уравнения смешивания цветов. Вот код:

```
int srcA = (int)((color >> 24 & 0xff)*bright);
if(coffLight > 0 && srcA > 0) {
    int srcR = color >> 16 & 0xff;
    int srcG = color >> 8 & 0xff;
    int srcB = color & 0xff;
    //смешиваем компоненты rgb цвета с компонентами rgb фона
    r = (int) (srcR * (srcA / 255.0) + r * (1 - srcA / 255.0));
    g = (int) (srcG * (srcA / 255.0) + g * (1 - srcA / 255.0));
    b = (int) (srcB * (srcA / 255.0) + b * (1 - srcA / 255.0));
}
```